increment not working for elements of an array
The code below does not increments the variables of the array even when there is no apparent reason for this, does anybody know why?
php > $a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
php > foreach($a as $k => $i) { $a[$k] = $i++; }
php > var_dump($a);
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
}


$i++ is "use then increment", so it doesn't actually increment $i until after it's been assigned to $a[$k]. If you want to increment and assign, use ++$i. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php
